# Client needs Ubercart member sign up function, but there is error with edit/option_prices

Tags: ubercart

I have a Drupal 7 client with Ubercart installed. They would like to add a Membership feature to their site where the members can receive a discount on their products and services.

We have Ubercart Price Per Role installed (in spite of it not being updated since 2013 which makes me nervous), which has added a nice little Member Price field in Product. I have added a test Product Class called Memberships to allow for membership levels.

I understand that a Role can be assigned to a Product Class through Attributes and Options to allow for membership expiration dates. Attributes and options have worked just fine for other products, but when I clicked the link for 'Note: "Price" column is the default option price. To set option prices per role use the options prices form.' 'I get The requested page "/?q=node/test/edit/option_prices" could not be found.'

Now it is entirely possible that I am trying to do it all wrong and that fixing that error won't get me the solution I'm looking for.   So, I would also like to hear hetherw I just headed down a rabbit hole, as well as finding out why the edit page cannot load.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem it sounds like it's an issue with the menu tab links being generated for your nodes; **node/test/edit/option_prices** isn't a valid path, it should should be something like **node/$nid/edit/option_prices**.

The [module enables that path](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uc_price_per_role/tree/uc_price_per_role.module#n34) if the UC Attributes module is enabled. It sounds like you've installed that module so I would substitute "test" with whatever product NID you're trying to test. Once you've confirmed it's working there, you can troubleshoot why your tab link is generating a bogus path.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your answer. When you say node/$nid, do you mean a product node? The reason I am asking is that the link is in this message on the admin page, as opposed to a node page: "Note: "Price" column is the default option price. To set option prices per role use the options prices form." Options prices form is linked, but that is the link that isn't working.

Comment: Yes, the registered menu path is a `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` under `node/%node/edit`. That sets it as a tab link on the product node edit page. This path can be accessed else where but it needs to be structured as `node/$nid/edit/option_prices` (where $nid is the product node id you're editing).